# Load a Haskell program as config (like xmonad)

Tags: haskell, dynamic, configuration-files

I know that xmonad’s configuration file is essentially a small Haskell program. I would like to do the same but don't seem to be able to understand from xmonad’s code how it is done. Would anyone please care to explain this to me in a slightly more foolproof way?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in how Xmonad does it?  Or are you asking more generally how one should load an Xmonad-style configuration file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`xmonad` is a library for writing window managers. The default window manager includes a keybinding which looks in a standard place for the source code of a new window manager, invokes GHC to build this source, then execs the newly built window manager. State is preserved by passing the current state on the command line and letting the new process deal with converting the information from the old process into the format needed for the new one (and sometimes this doesn't work, and the state is lost).

The whole pattern is bundled together as a library in [dyre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dyre).

Comment: Oh my, oh my, how cool is that! It is precisely the opportunity to learn about such solutions that makes struggling with Haskell so enjoyable for me. Thanks a lot!